# My app in Android don't show in google play for some tablet

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest

I've got a problem with my tablet and my app in google play, my app run fine in my tablet, but when try install from google play my app don't show.

My manifiest.xml:

```
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"  android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="false" />

<supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"/>
```

and I run "aapt dump badging" tools and this is the result:

```
sdkVersion:'7'
targetSdkVersion:'16'
uses-permission:'android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION'
uses-permission:'android.permission.CAMERA'
uses-permission:'android.permission.INTERNET'
uses-permission:'android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
uses-feature-not-required:'android.hardware.camera'
uses-feature-not-required:'android.hardware.camera.autofocus'
uses-feature-not-required:'android.hardware.location.gps'
uses-feature-not-required:'android.hardware.location.network'
uses-feature-not-required:'android.hardware.location'
application-icon-160:'res/drawable-mdpi/ic_launcher.png'
application-icon-240:'res/drawable-hdpi/ic_launcher.png'
application-icon-320:'res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_launcher.png'
application-icon-480:'res/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_launcher.png'
uses-permission:'android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
uses-implied-permission:'android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE','requested WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
uses-feature:'android.hardware.touchscreen'
uses-implied-feature:'android.hardware.touchscreen','assumed you require a touch screen unless explicitly made optional'
uses-feature:'android.hardware.screen.landscape'
uses-implied-feature:'android.hardware.screen.landscape','one or more activities have specified a landscape orientation'
main
other-activities
supports-screens: 'small' 'normal' 'large' 'xlarge'
supports-any-density: 'true'
locales: '--_--' 'en'
densities: '160' '240' '320' '480'
```

What can be the problem? Any idea??

**NOTE**: My tablet is a **BQ EDISON 2 QC**

Comment: Which android version have your tablet ?

Comment: the version is Android 4.2 Jelly Bean.

Comment: You can upload several APK to the Play Store (and not submit them to production) to see the dialog showing what the changes are and if it support more or less devices.
But it might be the autofocus thing. Also, why do  you have a supports-screens tag if you support all of them ?

Comment: Hi, To solve my problem I read many forums and tried lots of things and the support-screens tag was of the last things I tried to try to solve it without success.